# Intellij do not work with Datanucleus

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, datanucleus

I create a module for compiling my java projet in Intellij and I also have installed the plugins for Dataneucleus. In the plugin, I've checked the checkbox for enabling enhancer on my project, I've chosed JDO.

The compilation works correctly and I can see that my classes are enhanced.

Then, I've setup an artifact to generate a war and my run configuration simulates a tomcat 7 server.

After that, when I run my configuration server, Tomcat Log gives me an error :

```
org.datanucleus.api.jdo.exceptions.ClassNotPersistenceCapableException: The class "model.Mem" is not persistable. This means that it either hasnt been enhanced, or that the enhanced version of the file is not in the CLASSPATH (or is hidden by an unenhanced version), or the Meta-Data/annotations for the class are not found.
    at     
org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:350)
at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.jdoMakePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:736)
at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.makePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:756)
```

I don't understand what happens because I'm pretty sure that my classes are correctly enhanced. However, maybe the jar is not well compiled and it doesn't contains the right classes.

After some investigation, I decided to create my own Ant Task. However, it doesn't enhance my classes.

```
DataNucleus Enhancer (version 3.1.1) : Enhancement of classes
DataNucleus Enhancer completed and no classes were enhanced. Consult the log for full details
```

Here's the trace of the dataneucleus log :

```
2015-01-07 08:35:29 INFO  Enhancer:77 - DataNucleus Enhancer for API "JDO"
2015-01-07 08:35:29 INFO  Enhancer:77 - DataNucleus Enhancer (version 3.1.1) : Enhancement of classes
2015-01-07 08:35:29 DEBUG Enhancer:58 - DataNucleus Enhancer : Classpath
2015-01-07 08:35:29 DEBUG Enhancer:58 - >>  /Users/XXX/repository/EC2/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes
2015-01-07 08:35:29 DEBUG Enhancer:58 - >>  /Users/XXX/repository/EC2/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/aopalliance-repackaged-2.2.0.jar
2015-01-07 08:35:29 DEBUG Enhancer:58 - >>  /Users/XXX/repository/EC2/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/asm-4.0.jar
... I cut the log because it displays all jars that are in my classpath...
2015-01-07 08:35:29 INFO  Enhancer:77 - DataNucleus Enhancer completed and no classes were enhanced. Consult the log for full details
```

And here is the target of my Ant Task ( I only show a part of my Ant Task, I can show all if you one):

```
    <echo message="==================================================================="/>
    <echo message="Enhancing the MODULE files"/>
    <echo message="==================================================================="/>

    <!-- the classpath to enhance -->
    <path id="module.enhancer.classpath">
        <pathelement location="${module.classes.dir}"/>
        <path refid="module.lib.classpath"/>
    </path>

    <!-- define the task enhancer -->
    <taskdef name="nucleusenhancer"
             classpathref="module.enhancer.classpath"
             classname="org.datanucleus.enhancer.tools.EnhancerTask"/>

    <!-- enhance -->
    <nucleusenhancer classpathref="module.enhancer.classpath" verbose="true">
        <sysproperty key="log4j.configuration" value="file:log4j_enhancer.properties"/>
    </nucleusenhancer>



</target>
```

I'd be happy if you can help me to find why the enhancer doesn't enhance my classes. Because, if we see in the log, the enhancer loads correctly my directory where the classes are located.

Do you have a clue to give me?

Thanks!

Comment: If I decompile my classe, here is an example : '@PersistenceCapable(
    detachable = "true"
)
public class ITFirm implements Serializable {'

Comment: You're right, dataneucleus doesn't enhance my classes! Do you know if I can generate an 'Ant' to enhance my classes during the compilation?

Comment: I've created my ant and I can see that my classes are generated in 2 forms : MyClass.class and QClass.class. I guest It's correctly enhanced. However, when I deploy my jar, I've again this error message "No metadata has been registered for class MyClass". Do you have any idea? Do I have to specify something ? I use :http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/guides/ant/enhancingwithant.html

Comment: Yes, here is the beginning of my class : MyClass.class that has been enhanced into QMyClass.class : public class QMyClass extends org.datanucleus.api.jdo.query.PersistableExpressionImpl<GFileOverview> implements PersistableExpression<GFileOverview>
{
    public static final QGFileOverview jdoCandidate = candidate("this");

Comment: But That's strange because the enhancing generates 2 mors files for each class. One is QClassName.class and the second QClassName.java

Comment: Hi @NeilStockton, I add a new answer to be more clear in my description. Thanks again for you help.

Comment: Sorry @NeilStockton, I edited my question.

Comment: And where do you specify WHICH classes to enhance??? This page http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_0/jdo/enhancer.html#ant explains how to define that, persistenceUnit? dir?

Comment: Thanks, everything works!